# How do I always run a "clean up" command in bash propagating the previous error code?

Tags: node.js, bash, testing, npm

I'm setting up tests for a Node.js project. The tests include interacting with static content (images) that is supposed to be served from a local [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

When the tests have completed - either successfully or failing - I want to end the server process and exit with a correct code. What I came up with in my npm scripts is the following:

```
"server": "http-server testdata -p 9876 -s",
"testcmd": "...",
"test": "npm run server & npm run testcmd && kill $(lsof -t -i:9876) || (kill $(lsof -t -i:9876) && exit 1)",
```

which "works", but has two problems:

- it repeats code as I do not know how to run things in any case instead of defining `||` and `&&` cases
- any non-zero exit code of `testcmd` will always be transformed into an `1` exit code - ideally I would like to propagate the exact exit code

I tried reading up on this and found people talking about traps, but could not get it to work.

What would be a good way to simplify this control flow scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two problems are connected: it would be easier to achieve what you're after if your command were better factored.

Since you do not want to set up a trap (and for this task, I don't blame you), what you need to do is *capture* the exit status of `testcmd` so that you can reiterate it later.  Having done that, you can run your cleanup unconditionally, and therefore without duplication.  For example:

```
npm run server & (npm run testcmd; status=$?; kill $(lsof -t -i:9876); exit $status)
```

Perhaps the special `$?` parameter, which expands to the exit status of the most recently executed [partial] pipeline, is the piece you were missing.

Comment: Perfect, capturing the exit code in a variable was exactly what I would have wished for. Thanks!